# apacite removes all author initials except the first in the reference list

Tags: bibtex, apa-style

I seem to have a problem with the `apacite` package.

Let's take as an example a reference in which the author names are Buller, D.B. and Burgoon, J.K.

This is what the full reference in the reference list should look like:

> Buller, D.B., & Burgoon, J.K. (1996). Interpersonal Deception Theory. *Communication Theory, 6*(3), pp. 203-242.

Instead, however, when I render this in Latex it comes out like this:

> Buller, D., & Burgoon, J. (1996). Interpersonal Deception Theory. *Communication Theory, 6*(3), pp. 203-242.

Notice that the last initials have disappeared. This happens with all my references; all initials are removed, except the first one. So if the initials would be A.B.C., B and C would be removed, and only A would be left. The same goes for A.B.C.E. and so on.

I manage my .bib file with JabRef 2.10 and I use TexMaker for OSX to create my tex and corresponding pdf files.

I'm at a loss here, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Below you can find an MWE for the tex file, and the content of my .bib file. 
Thanks in advance!

**MWE tex**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{apacite}


\begin{document}

The Interpersonal Deception Theory was developed by \citeA{buller1996}. 

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{references.bib}

\end{document}
```

**references.bib**

```
% This file was created with JabRef 2.10.
% Encoding: MacRoman


@Article{buller1996,
  Title                    = {Interpersonal Deception Theory.},
  Author                   = {Buller, D.B. and Burgoon, J.K.},
  Journal                  = {Communication Theory},
  Year                     = {1996},
  Number                   = {3},
  Pages                    = {pp. 203-242},
  Volume                   = {6},

  Owner                    = {idriesal-bender},
  Timestamp                = {2015.07.03}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two initials should be two distinct tokens for BibTeX, so you should separate them by a space:

```
@Article{buller1996,
  Title                    = {Interpersonal Deception Theory.},
  Author                   = {Buller, D. B. and Burgoon, J. K.},
  Journal                  = {Communication Theory},
  Year                     = {1996},
  Number                   = {3},
  Pages                    = {pp. 203-242},
  Volume                   = {6},
  Owner                    = {idriesal-bender},
  Timestamp                = {2015.07.03}
}
```

and leave to the bibliography style the actual typesetting, which can be the initials with no space, with a thin space or with a normal space.

[image]

Since the style you're using abbreviates the given names anyway, you *could* do

```
Author = {Buller, {\relax D.B} and Burgoon, {\relax J.K}},
```

to force no space, but I'd avoid it.

**Note** Don't use the `.bib` extension in the argument to `\bibliography`: it works only if you use MiKTeX and will raise errors with other TeX distributions: use

```
\bibliography{references}
```

I'd also prefer

```
Pages = {203-242},
```

leaving to the bibliography style the rendering.

Comment: Concerning the "pp. 203-242", I would normally leave the formatting to the bibliography style. However, my institution requires me to have the "pp." prefix with page numbers in the reference list and `apacite` doesn't produce the "pp." prefix.